# Running spark beeline on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am using beeline to execute hql queries.
The job does not seem show up in resource manager for Spark History server on HDP 2.6. 
How to make it run on Yarn?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beeline is an Apache Hive client and has nothing to do with Spark so you won't see queries show up in the Spark history server. The queries should be running in YARN though, and if you go to the YARN Resource Manager Web UI (should be under quick links if you have access to Ambari) you will see them there.

Comment: It is possible Connecting to the Spark SQL Thrift server using Beeline?